# Cakephp 2.9.0 Authentication not working,$this->Auth->login always return false

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

i have a login table

```
logins
------
email,password

AppController.php
---------------------

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Js', 'Cache', 'Flash');

public $components = array(
    'RequestHandler', 'Paginator',
    'Session', 'Flash',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize'=> array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                ),
                'userModel' => 'Login',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password',
                )
            ),
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'AccessMethods', 'action' => 'index'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);
```

AppController Before filter function

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Login';
    $this->Auth->allow(array('login','logout'));

    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Login'),
        'Basic',
        'Form'
    );
    $this->Auth->authorize='Controller';
    $this->Auth->authError = "You don't have access to that area. Please login first.";
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'Logins', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'Homes', 'action' => 'index');

}
```

In my loginController i added the beforeFilter and load the components
     LoginsController.php
     -------------------

```
 if($this->request->is('post'))
   {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {

        $this->Flash->success(__('Login Success'),'default',  array
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
         }

    else {

        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or Password is
        incorrect Please try   again'));
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
       }
   }
```

and also Before saving the login details i hashed the password in beforeSave method of login model

```
      public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
        $this->data['Login'
        ]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data['Login']['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now after writing the above codes,

1. I can save the hashed passwod
2. I can see the request data from the login form
   Problem
   1.$this->Auth->login() always return false
   what i tried already
3. Change the password hasher blowfish and tried to add a new entry in the login table and tried to login -NOt working same output
4. Checked the submitted password and stored password manually using PasswordHasher check fuction , that works fine

Please help me to get out of this, i have already worked on several cakephp projects,but i am working first time in 2.9.0

**Edit**

```
Create table logins query
              CREATE TABLE `logins` (
               `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
               `password` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
              `is_active` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
             `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
              `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
             `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
             `remember_token` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                 KEY `fk_logins_groups1_idx` (`group_id`),
            CONSTRAINT `fk_logins_groups1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) 
            REFERENCES `groups` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please post your `logins`table create statement: `SHOW CREATE TABLE logins;`

Comment: Also, please clarify what is the name of the method that contains the code in the third snippet (`if($this->request->is('post'))...`

Comment: @InigoFlores i checked that,
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Login',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'Logins','action'=>'login')));

Comment: @InigoFlores i updated the question with the table structure
please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @InigoFlores also my $this->request returns (
    [Login] => Array
        (
            [email] => xxx@gmail.com
            [password] => xxxx
        )

)

Comment: Thanks for providing the requested code. First of all, I would get rid of `AppController::beforeFilter()`. The options in there are in conflict with the ones provided in the `public $components` array. You need one or the other, but not both. You can pretty much delete the method altogether after setting the right parameters in the `$components` array. Second, I need to know the code inside `LoginsController::login()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125263/discussion-between-sibin-francis-and-inigo-flores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it in cakephp2.9.0. i used Blowfish Password Hasher and the problem was on my database users table, the password field length i have set to 255 and it work for me.please check your users table password field length.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solved it

I followed everything that provided in the 2.X Book
but simply add the following in AppController

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

if you choose any of the password hasher like simplePassword hasher or Blowfish
this works 
Thanks a lot.